# My string check doesnt work and I dont know what is the most eficient method to do it

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, conditional-statements, dry

So I have a code to check if a string matches a certain pattern, this pattern:

```
555-555-5555
(555)555-5555
(555) 555-5555
555 555 5555
5555555555
1 555 555 5555
```

for exemple this should return true:

```
1 456 789 4444
```

but it doesnt here's my code:

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  str = str.split('');
  for (let c in str) {
    if (str[c].match(/[0-9]/) && str[c] !== '5') {
      str.splice(c, 1, 5);
      console.log(str)
    }
    if (str.join('') === '555-555-5555' |str.join('') === '(555)555-5555' |str.join('') === '(555) 555-5555' |str.join('') === '555 555 5555' |str.join('') === '5555555555' |str.join('') === '5 555 555 5555') {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
}

console.log(telephoneCheck("1 456 789 4444"));
```

and as you can see the way I did it is DRY

I was especting for when it matched the patters to return true else false, I dont know for sure whats hapening actualy

Comment: There is a difference between `||` and `|` in javascript, you should use `||`. Also, it would be easier to use a loop

Comment: Try this expression ^(\+?1\s?)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$

Comment: splicing the array while it is being iterated is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @Konrad return statement should be moved out of loop too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the tool [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for you:

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {
    const pattern = /^(1\s?)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})([\s\-]?)\d{3}([\s\-]?)\d{4}$/;
    return pattern.test(str);
}

console.log(telephoneCheck("1 456 789 4444")); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

I would convert it to a regular expression

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`555-555-5555
(555)555-5555
(555) 555-5555
555 555 5555
5555555555
1 555 555 5555`
.replace(/5/g, '\\d')
.replace(/\(/, '\\(')
.replace(/\)/, '\\)')
.split('\n').join('|')
)

console.log(regex.test('1 456 789 4444'))
```